# PHP get warning and error messages?

Tags: php, error-handling

I want to get warning and error messages into php $variables so I save them to my database.

For example when there is any kind of error, warning or similar:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /example.php(136) on line 9
Warning: [...]
```

I want to get them to variable $error_code

How is this done?

Comment: Try to read from the `error_log` file and write it in the database.

Comment: You should take a look at this if you want it saved to a variable: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.phperrormsg.php

Comment: You can't catch parse errors, unless they're in a script that you `include` or `require`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For the simple case of just logging them:

```
set_error_handler(function($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) use ($db) {
    // log in database using $db->query()
});
```

Instead of just logging them into your database (with the likelihood you will not look at them after a while), you can also let those warnings, notices, etc. generate an Exception:

```
function exception_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
{
    if (error_reporting()) { // skip errors that were muffled
        throw new ErrorException($errstr, $errno, 0, $errfile, $errline);
    }
}

set_error_handler("exception_error_handler");
```

Source: [`ErrorException`](http://php.net/errorexception)

An exception will have more serious side effects, so you should have an [exception handler](http://www.php.net/set_exception_handler) in place to prevent the uncaught exception to cause a white page of death.

Answer (score 3):

Look into [`set_error_handler()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php)

> Sets a user function (error_handler) to handle errors in a script.
>
> This function can be used for defining your own way of handling errors
>   during runtime, for example in applications in which you need to do
>   cleanup of data/files when a critical error happens, or when you need
>   to trigger an error under certain conditions (using trigger_error()).

Answer (score 2):

I'm using `error_get_last();` until I find a better solution

```
$lastError = error_get_last();
echo $lastError ? "Error: ".$lastError["message"]." on line ".$lastError["line"] : "";
// Save to db
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a variable called $php_errormsg which gets the previous error message. Check here for more info - http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.phperrormsg.php